# Is there something incorrect about the phrase "fall back asleep"?

Tags: expressions, tenses

A quick Google search shows that the phrase seems to be in relatively common usage, but for some reason I find the construct very awkward.

I would say "fall asleep" the first time, and then "fall back to sleep" if awakened.

Saying "fall back asleep" sounds wrong to me in a similar way to "(I tripped but am) back running".  Is something wrong with the tense?  A case of "coming back to the present"?

Comment: Nothing incorrect *per se*. It's perfectly acceptable and makes sense in the appropriate context. Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/131778/14666 That may help understand the usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't see any reason to dispute the grammaticality of *fall back asleep*, but two things that *did* (mildly) surprise me when I looked into usage patterns were:-

1. It's almost as common as *fall back **to** sleep* (which version sounds far more natural to me).
2. Both usages were [relatively uncommon](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fell%20back%20asleep,fell%20back%20to%20sleep&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,fell%20back%20asleep;,c0;.t1;,fell%20back%20to%20sleep;,c0) until just a few decades ago.

[image]

(I see no evidence of any significant US/UK split in terms of either preference or prevalence.)

---

My guess is that both OP and myself find the *asleep* version less acceptable because it doesn't fit the same pattern as ***go** back to sleep* (where [*go back asleep* is virtually unknown](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=go%20back%20asleep,go%20back%20to%20sleep&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,go%20back%20asleep;,c0;.t1;,go%20back%20to%20sleep;,c0)).

Comment: I wonder if there is in fact a US/UK split, or some other regional distinction. In my case (southern US), "fall back asleep" seems more familiar/natural, and "fall back to sleep" is the "odd" one (in spite of "go back to sleep" seeming perfectly natural).

Comment: @pyobum: Toggling between the two corpuses doesn't suggest any significant UK/US difference, as mentioned in the answer. But it occurs to me another reason I might find ***to sleep*** more consistent is because [nobody likes ***get back asleep***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=get+back+asleep%2Cget+back+to+sleep&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cget%20back%20to%20sleep%3B%2Cc0) either. Despite the fact that total instances of ***asleep, to sleep,*** and ***sleeping*** are all about equally common both sides of the pond.

Comment: You can't analyse grammaticality of candidate variants of idioms other than by examining usage. 'Fall to sleep' is an idiom (it has to be 'fall into unconsciousness', not 'fall to unconscious/ness'), and 'fall to sleep' and 'fast asleep' are fine while trying to amalgamate them doesn't work.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Did you mean that "fall to sleep" is *not* idiomatic? Google Ngrams shows that "fall asleep" is far more prevalent.

Comment: @RosieF: My first thought was that [***He fell to sleep***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=He+fell+asleep%2CHe+fell+to+sleep&year_start=1600&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) sounded like an antiquated / archaic / Shakespearean usage. But as that NGram shows, comparatively speaking it never had any currency compared to ***He fell asleep***.

Comment: ...and as [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=He+fell+to+sleep&year_start=1600&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CHe%20fell%20to%20sleep%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2CHe%20fell%20to%20sleep%3B%2Cc0) shows, what little currency ***He fell to sleep*** has is basically as an *extremely* minority C20 usage.

Comment: @Rosie F 'Fall to sleep' is acceptable (14m raw Google hits for "fell to sleep"), though as FF says 'fall asleep' is easily the more common. Probably, padding ('fell **back** asleep/to sleep') affects the ratios quite significantly.

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that it is "back" that calls for "to", in the same way that "out" calls for "of". Probably due to the fact that back  is usually used with verbs of motion
I always use back To sleep

Answer (score -1):

> Saying "fall back asleep" sounds wrong to me.

This is an idiosyncrasy: there is nothing wrong with it.

How do you feel about this identical construction?

“He went to town and came back **drunk**.” In which “drunk” is the same adjectival free modifier as “asleep” is in your example.

Comment: That doesn't look like the same construction at all. "He came back drunk" means "he came back, and he was drunk when he came back." "He fell back asleep" does not mean "he fell back, and he was asleep when he fell back."